# Can button_to generate <button> tag instead of <input type="submit" />?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, button

Rather than

```
<input type="submit" />
```

I want to output

```
<button>
```

using the button_to method (rails 3.0.0)

Is this possible?

Comment: `button` is not specific to HTML5, nor is `input` for buttons deprecated in HTML5.

Comment: Actually, `<button>` already exists in HTML 4.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, its more a preference of mine to use buttons because of the flexibility of content and ease of styling. I like to style all default tags, so keeping buttons outside of inputs helps.

Answer (score 10):

As of the latest version of Rails (4.0.2, not sure about previous versions) passing a block to [button_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) invokes branch logic in the helper that creates a button element instead of an input.

For example, if you wanted to make a 'delete' button element in haml, bootstrap & fontawesome (my use case):

```
= button_to(foo_path(@foo),
  class: 'btn btn-sm', method: :delete, remote: true) do
  <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
```

If you want them to just always be button elements no matter what, you could always have your button content inside a block instead of the first argument. Not sure what the trade-off is there.

Answer (score 5):

You could override the `button_to` helper in `ApplicationHelper` to render a `button` tag instead. Look at the code that `button_to` already has and modify it to suit your purposes.

Comment: Why was this answer voted down? Its seems like a reasonable suggestion to me? Is there a problem with overriding button_to?

Comment: @SteveSmith Probably the lack of example.

Comment: Also, overriding helpers, more generally known as monkey-patching, isn't future-proof. Since this is view code where nothing depends on it, maybe you care less?

Answer (score 5):

I just found that changing button_to to using a **block** generates button tag instead of input:

so:

```
<%= button_to account_path(@account), data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}, method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-default btn-danger' do %>
  Inactivate
<% end %>
```

Generates:

```
<form method="post" class="button_to" action="/accounts/30">
  <div>
    <input type="hidden" value="delete" name="_method">
      <button type="submit" data-confirm="Are you sure?" class="btn btn-default btn-danger">
          Inactivate
      </button>
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="authenticity_token">
  </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: I am too lazy to override the button_to method so this worked for me :)

Answer (score 3):

from what i can see Rails already has a helper to output  tags; it's called `button_tag` (instead of `button_to`).

so, you could just use the following in your views, i see no need to override button_to:

```
<%= button_tag "Button Text", :class => "btn", :type => "submit" %>
```

no need to override. also, it's recommended to always supply the :type parameter since  is rendered different in different browsers.

Comment: This is not what `button_to` does.

Comment: @ClemensHelm can you explain more your downvote? I don't even mention what button_to is supposed to do in my answer. Can you let me know how the answer is wrong or how it can be improved?

Comment: I think what @Clemens Helm is trying to say is that `button_to` generates a form. The original poster wants to generate a form with a `button` of type submit instead of an `input` tag.

Comment: @Mohamad and @ClemensHelm I think you are both mistaken--why are you talking about button_to??? my solution is to use button_TAG, which *does* generate a `button` tag, *not* an `input` tag. That's why i specifically say don't use button_TO but use button_TAG. Here's the API: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-button_tag    if you are mistaken please remove the downvote. thanks!

Comment: @FireDragon fair point. I miss read, or rather, not read properly. My apologies.

Comment: @FireDragon While your answer isn't necessarily wrong - `button_tag` indeed generates a button - it's wrong in context of the question. OP asked how to generate a form with a button submit tag using the `button_to` method, your answer simply says how to generate a button which doesn't answer his question, hence your 3, now 4 down votes.

Comment: @Noz my solution is the best and easiest to use. The original question incorrectly assumes that you would want to override or use 'button_to' to generate '<button>' html. If anybody is down voting then please offer a better solution than the one I have offered. If you want a '<button>' tag in your form, my solution is best, no? In my opinion other solutions offered to override 'button_to' are the solutions that should be downvoted; this just isn't necessary to get what you want. I addressed the original question completely and offered a better, working solution. IMO this shouldn't be downvoted

Comment: "OP asked how to generate a `form` with a `button submit tag` using the button_to method". There's two requirements there, you're only addressing half of it. You could argue that it's not a lot of work to stick a `button_tag` inside a `form_for`, but that defeats the purpose of having convenient helper methods - to dry up your views. IMO, Ryan's answer is more appropriate.

Comment: This question did help me out without a need to override!

Comment: "If you want a '<button>' tag in your form, my solution is best" That's not what the OP wanted. He doesn't have a form, and wants a helper that generates *both* a form, and a button element that submits the form. Rails ships with `button_to` that does *almost* exactly this, but uses an input element instead of a button element. Hopefully it's obvious and uninteresting to him (and me) that he could have manually created a form and a button.

Comment: i agree with both sides here -- my answer doesn't precisely/exactly answer the original post. i get that and thanks for pointing this out. was just trying to help and didn't realize this discrepancy at the time. it looks like this answer is helping others with a viable alternative though so hopefully it's worth something there. hope this clears any confusion going on. thanks to all who commented!

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 7, the `button_to` view helper will render a `<button>` element, regardless of whether or not the content is passed as the first argument or as a block.

Answer (score 0):

I generally just stick this in my application_helper.rb file:

```
  def button_tag(text, options={})
    content_tag(:button, {:type => "submit"}.merge(options)) { text }
  end
```

You can then call it from a view like so:

```
button_tag "Save", :class => 'accept'
```

Comment: I guess this was downvoted because it's now in Rails: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-button_tag